# Undersampling and Oversampling

Tags: feature-selection, oversampling, under-sampling

I've an unbalanced dataset. I need do to perform feature selection and then I'm going to fit my model.

Is it conceptually wrong doing undersampling and perform feature selection and then once identified the most important features perform oversampling and fit the model on the data?

Comment: why do you want to oversample or undersample the data?  If it is for class imbalance reasons, it probably isn't a good idea.  Cost-sensitive learning is the best reason for resampling, but most method have better approaches (such as weighting the training data)